# Aren't SQL Server Views portable?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, view, database-schema, sql-view

During an application architecture review meeting, one of my colleagues said that, if we are going to make our schema portable (i.e. From SQL Server to Oracle/MySQL/Any other relational DB), we only have to stick to "Tables" and not create "Views"; as they are not portable.

I'm not convinced by the answer, as I see no reason why Views are not portable.
Can someone throw some light? I'm unable to get the right direction with search engines.

Comment: @Downvoter: Can you please comment why? Your reason could help improve myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic `CREATE VIEW` syntax containing a `SELECT` query is standard SQL<sup>1</sup> and has been for a very long time. However, certain *options* and *features*, such as schema-binding and *indexed* views are product specific.

Having Views and Tables, and having them be *largely interchangable* is based on the original relational model. [Codd's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules) include

> Rule 6:- The view updating rule:
>
> All views that are theoretically updatable are also updatable by the system.

---

Also, of course, having a portable schema is one of those things that sounds sensible but almost never works out in practice. There are too many actual deviations from the standards in real products. If you limit yourself to only the portable subset, you'll almost certainly have a broken database with half of the constraints that should be enforced not.

---

<sup>1</sup>The various SQL standards, as finally published, are not freely distributable. However, [this draft of the ANSI-92 standard](https://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt) (named after the year of its standardization) largely reflects what was in the standard and contains:

> ```
>      11.19  <view definition>
>
>      Function
>
>      Define a viewed table.
>
>      Format
>
>      <view definition> ::=
>           CREATE VIEW <table name> [ <left paren> <view column list>
>           <right paren> ]
>             AS <query expression>
>             [ WITH [ <levels clause> ] CHECK OPTION ]
>
>      <levels clause> ::=
>           CASCADED | LOCAL
>
>      <view column list> ::= <column name list>
> ```

Comment: Thank you @Damien_The_Unbeliever for the answer.

Comment: @DanGuzman, Thanks for that, and understood.  I usually wait for a day at least.

Comment: @CodeMad - and that's why I don't personally do these sort of chase up comments. If people engage with the site, sooner or later they'll accept answers on most of their questions. I can wait :-)